# Edit Entity Framework template file .tt for XmlIgnore

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, xmlserializer, xmlignore

I have Entity Framework 6 template file. I would like to include `[XmlIgnore]` on `public virtual ICollection` as it can not be serialized.

This template file generates designer class and I do not want to edit designer class to include `[XmlIgonre]` by editing designer class once it's generated. I want to edit template so all lines with  `public virtual ICollection` will have the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute.

Comment: Can you post somewhere the tt file you are using?

Comment: @AkosNagy , I can not post entire tt file but here is the code that is used for Xml  <#@ include file="EF.Reverse.POCO.ttinclude" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml.Schema" #>
<#    } #>

Comment: The tt file has to be modified at a number of places, but I can only tell where if I see the template.

Answer (score 2):

you must be find and edit this (in your model  tt file) :

```
<#
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            if (navigationProperty.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many)
            {
#>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
<#
            }
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }
#>
```

To this :

```
<#
        foreach (var navigationProperty in navigationProperties)
        {
            if (navigationProperty.ToEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many)
            {
#>
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
<#
            }
#>
    <#=codeStringGenerator.NavigationProperty(navigationProperty)#>
<#
        }
    }
#>
```

Comment: Perfect solution